# How to set 'Author' for a node type on a custom form?

Tags: forms, drupal-7, default-value

I have following code...

I have a node type called MY_NODE_TYPE.

I have set up a cusdtom URL for my node type: 'node/%/bla'). At this URL my 'default author' field is set to 'Anonymous' when it should be admin (uid 1).

I'd like to know where I should set uid to be 1 if following code does not work. (How can I make this code work?)

```
function bla_menu() {
  $items['node/%/bla'] = array(
  'title' => t('Bla'),
  'page callback' => 'bla_callback',
  );
}

function bla_callback () {
  module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
  $new_node = new stdClass;
  $new_node->type = 'bla';
  node_object_prepare($new_node);
  $new_node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
  $new_node->uid = 1;//This is wehre I set uid to be one and is not effective
  return drupal_get_form('MY_NODE_TYPE_form', $new_node);
}
```

Comment: It needed to set $new_node->name as well...

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [`hook_node_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to set the values you need to change there.

Code sample:

```
function MODULE_node_presave($node) {
    if($node->type === 'MY_NODE_TYPE') 
        $node->uid = 1;
}
```

Comment: I need a user set as a default Author on my form. This answer would not help.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to pass the default author?